# Non-independence of IVs in a random forest model

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, multicollinearity, independence

How is a random forest model affected if some of the variables are not independent?

Answer (score 6):

Random Forests are an ensemble model based on CARTs. Classification And Regression Trees are non-parametric which means they really dont have any assumptions on the independant variables you include. A little more detailed explanation would be that when you grow a tree, at each split, it must be decided what variable you are going to use. If the variables are non-independant doesn't matter. In the extreme case, if you have two perfectly correlated variables the splitting scheme would simply choose one of them randomly if they were to be candidates for that split. Maybe not even so as the variable selection for splitting is quite sensitive and can maybe find a better split using one variable over the other even if they are very similar.